# How to shrink secure file LOBs in Oracle

Tags: oracle, shrink, lob

I noticed today that SQL command that is used to shrink LOBs in oracle does not work in 12c.

```
ALTER TABLE SAMPLE_TABLE MODIFY lob (LOB_COLUMN) (SHRINK SPACE)
```

This returns oracle error

> ORA-10635: Invalid segment or tablespace type

In the oracle documentation it is mentioned that the SHRINK option is not supported for SecureFiles LOBs.

I want to know how blob compresses in secure files. Does oracle handles that internally?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure, but I think `shrink` is no longer required when using SecureFile storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE SAMPLE_TABLE MOVE LOB(LOB_COLUMN) STORE AS (TABLESPACE USERS)
```

Note: this is, unlike how it can be read, a `move lob` operation. It is a `move TABLE` operation, and while at it, moving a lob too.

This is why it invalidates indexes, - because it moves the whole table not just the lob. And of course it can take a very long time and it will consume 2x space during the operation, because oracle makes a copy of the data and only after it's complete it frees the old segments.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to shrink LOBs using SecureFiles, use this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE SAMPLE_TABLE MOVE LOB(LOB_COLUMN) STORE AS (TABLESPACE USERS)
```

**Be careful using it** - this command invalidates all indexes on `SAMPLE_TABLE`, so you should rebuild them after you're finished with LOBs:

```
ALTER INDEX <index_name> REBUILD;
```